# How to get a litteral 'aString' value match a litteral 'aString' type?

Tags: typescript

While converting a project to TypeScript, I reached the following issue.

When I remove the `as 'http'` casting here :
https://github.com/nfroidure/whook/blob/934864ee80cc0505420bff5db8bd4ded167c4f57/packages/whook-example/src/services/API.ts#L49

I get an error here:
https://github.com/nfroidure/whook/blob/934864ee80cc0505420bff5db8bd4ded167c4f57/packages/whook-example/src/services/API.ts#L101

It looks like the 'http' string is not recognized as an 'http' type ?!
You can easily live check the problem by running a copy of the project with the following command `npm init @whook`.

The error:

```
Argument of type '{ openapi: string; info: { version: string; title: any; description: any; }; servers: { url: string; }[]; components: { securitySchemes: { fakeAuth: { type: "apiKey"; description: string; name: string; in: string; }; bearerAuth: { ...; }; } | { ...; }; }; paths: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Document'.
  Types of property 'components' are incompatible.
    Type '{ securitySchemes: { fakeAuth: { type: "apiKey"; description: string; name: string; in: string; }; bearerAuth: { type: string; description: string; scheme: string; }; } | { bearerAuth: { type: string; description: string; scheme: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentsObject'.
      Types of property 'securitySchemes' are incompatible.
        Type '{ fakeAuth: { type: "apiKey"; description: string; name: string; in: string; }; bearerAuth: { type: string; description: string; scheme: string; }; } | { bearerAuth: { type: string; description: string; scheme: string; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: ReferenceObject | HttpSecurityScheme | ApiKeySecurityScheme | OAuth2SecurityScheme | OpenIdSecurityScheme; }'.
          Type '{ fakeAuth: { type: "apiKey"; description: string; name: string; in: string; }; bearerAuth: { type: string; description: string; scheme: string; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: ReferenceObject | HttpSecurityScheme | ApiKeySecurityScheme | OAuth2SecurityScheme | OpenIdSecurityScheme; }'.
            Property 'bearerAuth' is incompatible with index signature.
              Type '{ type: string; description: string; scheme: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ReferenceObject | HttpSecurityScheme | ApiKeySecurityScheme | OAuth2SecurityScheme | OpenIdSecurityScheme'.
                Type '{ type: string; description: string; scheme: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpSecurityScheme'.
                  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
                    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"http"'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit variable type fixes compilation error without (bad) cast:

```js
import { OpenAPIV3 } from 'openapi-types';

const API: OpenAPIV3.Document = {
  // ...
        type: 'http',
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with type inference indeed. Validating you're answer in the meanwhile but would like to get a more detailed answer with the why.

Comment: @nfroidure typescript won't keep the literal type for too long, especially not when declaring an object. So it will be promoted into a string. However, passing an exact type annotation when declaring your variable will constrain fields to be of certain types (literal types like in your example).